# Added activities, now names and labels and strings aren't registering Android Manifest file

Tags: android

I added all the classes as activities in the manifest file.  Then I went back to add labels (all the examples I saw had them).  I had to add string references and now the ones with more than one word aren't registering as having a resource yet they do.  Suggestions?  Please!  Thank ya'll....

```
    <activity android:name=".AbidingInChrist"
              android:label="@string/Abiding_in_Christ">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AbundantLiving"
              android:label="@string/Abundant Living">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AccessToGod"
              android:label="@string/Access to God">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AdorationOfGod"
              android:label="@string/Adoration of God">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AmazingGrace"
              android:label="@string/Amazing Grace">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AnsweredPrayer"
              android:label="@string/Answered Prayer">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Atonement"
              android:label="@string/Atonement">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Attitudes"
              android:label="@string/Attitudes">
```

All the ones with more than one word say they aren't resourced.  But I made strings for all of them:

```
 <string name="AbidingInChrist">Abiding in Christ</string>
<string name="AbundantLiving">Abundant Living</string>
<string name="AdorationofGod">Adoration of God</string>
<string name="AmazingGrace">Amazing Grace</string>
<string name="AnsweredPrayer">Answered Prayer</string>
<string name="Atonement">Atonement</string>
<string name="Attitudes">Attitudes</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<activity android:name=".AbidingInChrist"
          android:label="@string/Abiding_in_Christ">
```

to

```
<activity android:name=".AbidingInChrist"
          android:label="@string/AbidingInChrist">
```

It seems that you have put in spaces and underscores when trying to reference the strings, even though the labels for those strings don't include these spaces and underscores. You should remove all spaces and underscores in your `android:label` attributes for each reference

Comment: Thanks.  I did that and it worked except I had to retype some of them over and over again in Eclipse to get them to take.  Glitch I presume.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

When you reference a string defined in your `strings.xml` using `@string/`, you need to use the string resource's name, not its content.

For example, `@string/Answered Prayer` should be `@string/AnsweredPrayer`.

Similarly, if you reference a string resource in Java, you still use the name, not the content (e.g. `R.string.AnsweredPrayer`).